# Ist "verunmöglichen" Standarddeutsch?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

Ist das Wort "verunmöglichen" als Gegensatz von "ermöglichen" Standarddeutsch? Bin darüber schon mehrfach gestolpert, aber das Wort "fühlt" sich irgendwie schräg an.

Comment: Ich denke nicht. Ich habe das Wort noch nie gehört oder benutzt.

Comment: der Duden kennt es und bis Du gefragt hast hat es sich für mich auch nicht schräg angefühlt (ist jetzt nicht mehr ganz so), auch im Herkunftsland scheint nicht jeder damit glücklich zu sein: http://www.blogwiese.ch/archives/229

Comment: @Devil0s: naja, ich hatte das mal mit einem anderen Wort vor mehr als zehn Jahren, seitdem bin ich belehrt. Auch Muttersprachler kennen nicht alle Facetten ihrer eigenen Sprache.

Comment: s.a *verunfallen*, *verunglücken*, *verunglimpfen*,... http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/, filtern nach "verun" für ungefähr 60 ähnlich unübliche Verben, die dem selben Schema folgen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Ja.

Es ist kein Dialektwort, sondern ein Wort, von dem man erwarten kann, es in einer Zeitung oder einem Buch zu lesen. Also Standarddeutsch. Außerdem wird es in renommierten Wörterbüchern gelistet:

- http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verunmoeglichen
- [https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/verunmöglichen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/verunm%C3%B6glichen)
- [https://dwds.de/wb/verunmöglichen](https://dwds.de/wb/verunm%C3%B6glichen)

Besonders häufig wurde es während des zweiten Weltkrieges verwendet:

[Ngram »verunmöglichen«](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=verunm%C3%B6glichen&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cverunm%C3%B6glichen%3B%2Cc0)
[image: verunmöglichen]

---

### Nachtrag

Das Institut für deutsche Sprache im Mannheim hat eine Grundformenliste aller deutschen Wörter erarbeitet, und diese Liste nach der Häufigkeit des Vorkommens in gedruckten deutschen Text sortiert. Das Ausgangsmaterial sind gedruckte Texte der Jahre 1983 bis 2012.

Das ist ein Ausschnitt aus dieser Liste, beginnend bei Platz 37.530, insgesamt 30 aufeinanderfolgende Einträge. Auf Platz 37.545 findet man das gesuchte Wort:

37530. Siegerteam
37531. Höcker
37532. Namenszusatz
37533. neuapostolisch
37534. Produktionsleiter
37535. Torausbeute
37536. Verformung
37537. Altöl
37538. Eingeweide
37539. Inuit
37540. Kinobetreiber
37541. Polizeikommissar
37542. Schulleben
37543. Sozialberatung
37544. überrunden
37545. **verunmöglichen** <== Hier steht das nachgefragte Wort
37546. Zuschauertribüne
37547. avisiert
37548. Markttreiben
37549. meldepflichtig
37550. Ortsbeigeordnete
37551. Superwahljahr
37552. Adventssingen
37553. Beratervertrag
37554. entschlafen
37555. Hedgefonds
37556. Sojabohne
37557. Einbettung
37558. Familienminister
37559. Flak

Dieser Quelle zufolge ist »verunmöglichen« also ziemlich gleich häufig wie »Altöl«, »Sojabohne«, »überrunden« und »Superwahljahr«.

Die ganze Liste hat übrigens 329.946 Einträge. Zu den seltensten Wörter in dieser Liste gehören »Ultrakurzwellenempfänger«, »Tabakraucherin«, »mensurabel«, »imbezill« und »schwachbevölkert«.

---

Einige Fundstellen für »verunmöglicht« im Netz:

**aus der Schweiz**

- Schweizer Tageszeitung *Soloturner Zeitung*: »[Neuer Zonenplan **verunmöglicht** Weiterbestehen des Tierparks](http://www.solothurnerzeitung.ch/solothurn/lebern-bucheggberg-wasseramt/pech-fuer-strickler-neuer-zonenplan-verunmoeglicht-weiterbestehen-des-tierparks-an-dieser-stelle-130566622)«
- Website des Schweizer Fernsehens *SRF*: »[Die Kontrolle des Staates wird erschwert bis **verunmöglicht**](http://www.srf.ch/news/schweiz/die-kontrolle-des-staates-wird-erschwert-bis-verunmoeglicht)«
- *Neue Zürcher Zeitung*: »[China **verunmöglicht** Debatte zu Tibet](https://www.nzz.ch/uno-menschenrechtsrat-debatte-tibet-verunmoeglicht-1.694850)«

**aus Österreich**

- Tageszeitung *Die Presse*: »[... ein Diskurs darüber wurde **verunmöglicht.**](http://diepresse.com/home/meinung/gastkommentar/5069820/Die-Partei-ohne-Eigenschaften)«
- Tageszeitung *heute*: »[..., die Familie wollte aber eine zweite Untersuchung des Leichnams, die dadurch **verunmöglicht** wurde.](http://www.heute.at/news/oesterreich/Ich-habe-Joerg-Haider-einbalsamiert;art23655,1130101)«
- Online-Portal *Schau auf Linz*: »[Nachdem ... den Radfahrern die Querung direkt bei der A7-Auffahrt **verunmöglicht** wurde, ...](http://schau.auf.linz.at/benutzer/meldungen/detail.html?id=/_data/messages/messages/message_0013853)«

**aus Deutschland**

- Website der deutschen *OnVista Bank*: »[Versand von rezeptfreien Arzneimitteln (OTC) faktisch **verunmöglicht**](http://www.onvista.de/news/versand-von-rezeptfreien-arzneimitteln-otc-faktisch-verunmoeglicht-14537163)«
- deutscher *Seniorentreff*: »[Soll das Einbinden externer Bilder **verunmöglicht** werden?](http://community.seniorentreff.de/forum/board/Soll-das-Einbinden-externer-Bilder-verunmoeglicht-werden;tpc4,329532,6)«
- *Finanzdiskurs.de*: »[Ärzte **verunmöglichen** Versicherungsschutz](http://finanzdiskurs.de/marktgeschehen/finanzpolitik/aerzte-verunmoeglichen-versicherungsschutz/)«

Answer (score 8):

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verunmoeglichen) fällt das Wort in den schweizerischen Wortschatz und die Verwendung scheint nicht allzu selten zu sein.

Ob das Wort im Grenzgebiet und im Süden der Bundesrepublik auch bekannt oder sogar verwendet wird, kann ich nicht beurteilen, aber nördlich der Mainlinie ist das Wort höchst selten bis nie im Wortschatz zu finden. Dort spricht man schlichtweg von "verhindern".

Comment: Aha, interessant. Dachte mir schon, daß eventuell aufgrund des Internets derlei Worte verbreitet werden. Habe das Wort nämlich mehrfach online gelesen. Danke und +1.

Comment: Ich kenne es, bin aber auch von südlich des Mains. Ich würde es im Normalfall nicht verwenden, weil es mit den beiden Vorsilben arg umständlich klingt; _zu_ umständlich, weil man ja auch "unmöglich machen" oder eben "verhindern" sagen kann.

Comment: Nördlich der Mainlinie wird es als Neologismus aufgenommen und verstanden.

Answer (score 2):

Zur Anwendung des Wortes:
Bei geeichten Geräten ist die Justiermöglichkeit zu verunmöglichen.

In diesem Zusammenhang ist es schön, dass unsere Sprache solche Worte bietet. Denn "unbrauchbar zu machen", "zu blockieren" oder wie hier "zu verhindern" treffen nicht den Kern des Problems, bzw. wären semantisch sogar Unsinn... Eine Möglichkeit zu verhindern?!?

Comment: Hm, schwanke zwischen »Das ist noch eine Antwort« und »Das ist schon ein Kommentar«. *Ist* das Wort nun standarddeutsch oder nicht? Das war die Frage, die es zu beantworten gilt.

Comment: Inwiefern ist "eine Möglichkeit verhindern" semantisch unsinniger als "eine Möglichkeit verunmöglichen"?

Answer (score -4):

Ja.
Bürokratendeutsch/gehoben:

> Etwas Verunzumöglichendes zu tun ist verboten.

Comment: Gefragt wurde nach einem Verb. Du behandelst in deiner Antwort ein Substantiv, also nicht das, wonach gefragt wurde. Auch die Klassifizierung als *Bürokratendeutsch/gehoben* trifft nicht zu.